# How to coerce application of check constraint on every modification

Tags: t-sql, check-constraints

Is it possible to configure a check-constraint so that it is applied (checked) on every modification? I.e., irrespective of whether or not the particular checked field is actually modified.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (
    Id   INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
  , Name NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
  , Who  NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_dbo_SomeTable_Who DEFAULT (SUSER_SNAME()) FOR Who;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_dbo_SomeTable_WhoEqualsUser CHECK (Who = SUSER_NAME());
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (Name) VALUES (N'SomeBody');


EXECUTE AS USER = N'NotMe';
GO
    UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET Name = N'SomebodyElse'; -- Want this update-attempt to throw an exception
        -- But it doesn't throw here because the check constraint isn't checked

    UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET Name = N'SomebodyElse'  -- Don't want this update-attempt to throw
                           , Who = N'NotMe'          -- since Who = SUSER_NAME()
GO
REVERT
```

Comment: I guess I should mentioned that I'm aware that this scenario can be accommodated using triggers. I'm just curious if there is a way using constraints.

Comment: Not really sure what you want to accomplish here. You don't change the value of the `Who` column just because you are executing as a different user - so obviously the check constraint will not return false...